# How to get the value on the List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void GametableHistory(bool success, Int32 gametable_no, Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 shoe_no, bc_gametable_history_list list)
{
    tzPlayInfo.Instance.gametable_history_list = list;

    string s1 = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        s1 += list[i].r;
        s1 += ",";
    }

    Debug.Log("This is a new history " + gametable_no + " = " + s1);
}
```

The output of this code are :

> This is a new history 1 = P  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,P  ,T  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,TP ,B P,PP ,P  ,T  ,P  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,P P,BP ,P  ,B  ,P  ,B P,BP ,B  ,T  ,P  ,P  ,P  ,BP ,P  ,B  ,P  ,PP ,P  ,P  ,
>
> This is a new history 2 = B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,BP ,P  ,P  ,BP ,P  ,T  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,P P,P  ,P  ,P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B P,P  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,B P,P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,
>
> This is a new history 3 = B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,BP ,P  ,P  ,BP ,P  ,T  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,P P,P  ,P  ,P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B P,P  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,B P,P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,
>
> This is a new history 4 = P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,T P,B  ,T  ,B  ,P  ,P P,P  ,P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,BP ,P  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,B P,P  ,P P,B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,T  ,BP ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B P,P P,B  ,P  ,P P,

My question is how can i get only the `History 1` and its value .

I tried doing it like this

```
s1 += list[0].r;
```

but the problem is that it only gets like this

> This is a new history 1 = P

Only 1 value. I want the whole new history 1 whole value.
Thanks

Comment: How did you get 4 outputs..... for ex......this is a new history 1 , 2, 3,4? Have we invoked the method `GametableHistory` 4 times? If yes, then invoke the method only for one time with appropiate `gametable_no`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kara was so near what i did here is like this

```
if (gametable_no == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list.Count; i++)
        {
            newString[0] += tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list[i].r;
            newString[0] += ",";
        }
        string[] newChars = newString[0].Split(',');
```

Thank you Kara

Answer (score 2):

Your function is called 4 times. The question is why is it called 4 times?

The simple solution would be:

```
private void GametableHistory(bool success, Int32 gametable_no, Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 shoe_no, bc_gametable_history_list list)
{
    if (gametable_no != 1) // Because you're only interested in table 1
        return;

    tzPlayInfo.Instance.gametable_history_list = list;

    string s1 = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        s1 += list[i].r;
        s1 += ",";
    }

    Debug.Log("This is a new history " + gametable_no + " = " + s1);
}
```

I don't know `GameTables`/`GameTableHistory` in unity. Did you create this class?

Comment: I need the other tables later actually for now i just want to print out the 1st table then next is the second table . How can i obtain that sir?

Comment: The example works for you. The function is canceled with the `return` in the `if`-clause. Only `gametable_no == 1` will be logged.

Comment: yeah i know . But is there a thing i could get those value from `gametable_no == 1` like this `s1 += list[0].r`

Comment: I created those class

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. `gametable_no == 1` is a comparesion which gives you a `true` or a `false`. `s1 += x` adds your variable `x` to your string `s1`.

Comment: If you want to run the whole function but only add values to `s1` it would be smth. like `if (gametable_no == 1) s1 += list[i].r + ",";`.

Comment: What i want to do is like this. `gametable_no == 1` then print out the whole table history then next i want to print the `gametable_no == 2` then also print out the whole value but what the problem is that this line of code ` s1 += list[0].r` is not working . I'm doing it like that because i only want for now the `gametable_no == 1` then parse it after parsing it next is the `gametable_no ==2` and so on.

Comment: Please provide a complete example with input and outputs. Show me your gametables and show me your desired log.